# Is there a grid view feature in Mac PowerPoint 2011?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2011

It seems like this feature is unavailable on a mac powerpoint 2011, and I don't mean "Static Guide"

Is there a grid view feature in Mac PowerPoint2011?